# Is it safe to design an API where a user can change his properties (email, first name, etc.) at the same time as their password?

Tags: api, rest, api-design

Are there any reasons to design an HTTP REST API that prevents its clients from changing a user's password at the same time as they change other properties on their user? For instance, I'd be interested in just allowing them to change it all at once. For instance, if a user wanted to change their password to "foobar" and their first name to "Bob", they could just send:

```
PATCH /user/myid HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{"password":"foobar","first_name":"Bob"}
```

I've seen some APIs prevent clients from changing the password at the same time as other properties, but I can't see the reason for this apparent restriction. Is there any reason to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Provided they provide their original password, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why they prevent this is they use an email TO the account associated with the password being reset which enables them to reset the password without the original pass.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simple enough to require something like `oldpassword`:

```
{
    "oldpassword":"barfoo",
    "newpassword":"foobar",
    "first_name":"Bob",
    "email":"newemail@company.com",
    "id":"unique_identifier_that_never_changes"
}
```

Then validate that oldpassword matches the current password.

You can then update `password`, `first_name`, and `email` for the unique `id` provided your validation of the old/current password is successful.